# Which Japanese sentence is grammatically correct?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese, grammar

My friend and I are making sentences from English to Japanese.

We are trying to turn this sentence into Japanese:

> I think he's 23 years old, I'm not sure however.

We came up with:

> 思う彼は23歳。分かりませんだけど。
>
> Omou kare wa 23sai. Wakarimasen dakedo.

and

> 思う彼は23歳だけど、分かりません。
>
> Omou kare wa 23sai dakedo, wakarimasen.

Which of these sentences are grammatically correct? If both were wrong, what would be the correct way to say it in Japanese?

Comment: 思う彼 means "he who thinks" not "I think he". I suggest you study some basic Japanese sentence structure before trying to  make your own sentences. It's very different from English. For example, verbs go at the end of the sentence/clause.

Comment: @user3856370 Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few ways you could go about phrasing this, depending on the nuance/context, but pretty plainly:

彼は２３歳だと思うけど、わからない。
(lit. I think he is 23 years old, but I don't know.)

The 思う has to come at the end of the phrase; in your examples, it modifies the 彼, which would mean "he who thinks" or similar.